# Read file not owned by me in a directory owned by me

Tags: linux, file-permissions

A daemon process running as a special user has created files which only its user can read. The directory is owned by me and I have write access to the directory. Is there any way that I can read or copy the files without sudo rights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have the permission to read it - therefore, you cannot read it.

You have permissions to change the directory - you can rename or remove the file.

In a way, you can access the file's name, but not its content.

Comment: I hoped there was some clever way around it since I own the parent directory. But it makes sense that I should not be able to read it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If it's a huge deal, you could just boot a live disc to read it in a round-about way...

Boot into the Live Disc (root login by default) and (all in the terminal):

> 1. Make a mountpoint: *mkdir /mnt/mountpoint*
> 2. Find your partition if you do not know it: *fdisk -l*
> 3. Mount it: *mount /dev/sdaX /mnt/mountpoint*
> 4. Go to the directory: *cd /mnt/mountpoint/home/(username)/dir/fileYouCantRead*
> 5. Just read the file to the terminal in Less: *cat fileYouCantRead | less*

That'll get you the contents - if it matters enough to do the process.